# How to stop certain parts of an mesh from deforming when posing armatures

Tags: rigging

when im posing with armatures my character decides to scruch up when i make look down then stretch when i look up.
[image]

[image]

this is the original model:
[image]

if anyone wants to know the mesh is made from multiple parts
if you have an answer id like to be informed

heres a copy of the files [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file, remove the pats that are not useful

Comment: how do i share the file?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.com/ (follow the instructions and share the link it will create)

Answer (score 0):

Some vertices are assigned to other vertex groups than *head*. To fix that, select the head in *Edit* mode, *Remove from All Groups*, then assign them to the group called *head*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! i just started making meshes and this really helped!

Comment: one more question... when i reassign the vertex groups i still want the neck part of the head to follow the neck bone is that possible or would i need to connect a certain part of my mesh to the other

Comment: In that case remove the vertices at the bottom of the neck from the vertex group called head and assigned to the one called neck

Comment: Ok! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Btw, put the Armature modifier on top of the modifiers stack, then Solidify, at last Subdivision Surface

Comment: is putting them first prioritize it more?

Comment: Yes the order matters, if you put Armature first, the armature will only manage the low-poly object, it will be much lighter to calculate, etc